# ANSI SQL - Convert scientific notation number

Tags: sql, toad, ansi-sql

I'm using Toad for Oracle and writing code in SQL (not PLSQL), so I'm assuming it is ANSI SQL.
I have some values in my data that have the following number 1.2705E+09.
How can I convert that into a normal number?

Thanks

Comment: Where is your data being viewed? select to_number('1.2705E+09') from dual; works just fine.

Comment: What's a normal number? That's a floating point value (e.g. REAL data type.) In ANSI SQL CAST is used to convert data to other data types, e.g. CAST(1.2705E+09 as integer).